# GetVersionEx reporting 12.2.18763 on Windows 10 1903

Tags: windows, manifest

Using the W*in32 GetVersion/GetVersionEx API* and after adding a compatibility manifest, Windows reports itself as **12.2.18763**.

It's common knowledge that Win32 applications on Windows 10 require a compatibility manifest in order to get the actual OS version. Without it, they only get **8.2.10200** (which I can reproduce here).

But once I add the manifest, Windows reports itself as **12.2.18763**. Of course I don't really own Windows 12 but rather Windows 10 1809 x64.

Compatibility manifest, copied from another StackOverflow answer:

```
<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
  <application>
    <!-- Windows Vista -->
    <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
    <!-- Windows 7 -->
    <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
    <!-- Windows 8 -->
    <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
    <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
    <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
    <!-- Windows 10 -->
    <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
  </application>
</compatibility>
```

Code copied from the GetVersionEx() MSDN page:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi;
    BOOL bIsWindowsXPorLater;

    ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));
    osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);

    GetVersionEx((OSVERSIONINFO*)&osvi);

    printf("Version is %d.%d (%d)\n",
        osvi.dwMajorVersion,
        osvi.dwMinorVersion,
        osvi.dwBuildNumber);
}
```

I'd expect *10.0.17763*, and *12.2.18763* is too close to be a general fault *(+2, +2, +1000).* I searched for the individual numbers, but I didn't find a hint.

Another common answer is compatibility shims, but I wouldn't expect them to *upgrade* the Windows version. I can't have messed with them because the Application Compatibility Manager is not installed on this system.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a shim, but from Application Verifier. I must have left the **HighVersionLie** box ticked when I tested the application earlier on.